# Given the declaration, `std::unique<T> p;`,why `!p` is legail since there is no memory function 'operator !()' for `std::unique<T>`

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

As the code below, I could not understand why `!p` is legail since there is no member function 'operator !()' for `std::unique<T>`.

As `std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;` is legal, i think `p` is an object ,not a pointer.So i am confused.

Could anybody do me a favor?

```
std::cout << "unique ownership semantics demo\n";
  {
      auto p = std::make_unique<D>(); 
      std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;  //I think p is an object, not an pointer.
      auto q = pass_through(std::move(p)); 
      assert(!p);  //Why it is legial?
      q->bar();   
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `!p` is compiled the compiler implicitly calls the `operator bool` that `unique_ptr<T>` has and then negates that.

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) for more details.

Comment: If i understand you corectly, `!my_object_name` would call the `operator bool` if the relate class created myself has the corresponding member function. Am i right?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Yes you're right. It's usual to make such operators `explicit` to prevent unwanted conversions. But even when explicit the conversion is performed in the contexts described in the link I gave.

Comment: Glad to see again.Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: One more question raises, why doesn't `std::unique_prt<T>` overload the `!` operator directly?

Comment: @sunshilong369 I'm not aware of any reason why that wouldn't work, but since the implicit conversion rules have been designed for classes which want to be implicitly convertable to bool there is no need. Though prior to C++11 a class like this would have overloaded `operator !`.

Comment: I am a novice in c++.I just think that it more clear to overload the `operator !` and no implicit conversion is neeeded any more.

Answer (score 3):

`!p` is legal since there is an explicitly defined function to convert a `unique_ptr` to `bool`.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool

> ```
> explicit operator bool() const noexcept;
> ```

`!p` is translated as `!(p.operator bool())`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question:

`std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;` works because

- `get()` returns the pointer held by the `unique_ptr`
- `operator<<` has an overload that accepts a `void*` pointer as input
- any pointer is implicitly convertible to `void*`.

`p` is indeed an object, not a pointer. But `get()` returns a pointer.